# Java Inspect File Contents

Tags: java, file, validation

I have a JEE6 app that accepts files via POST. I can perform server side basic test to ensure the file extension is correct but is there a way to inspect file contents to make sure I don't process it unless I'm happy its a valid file i.e. to avoid someone just renaming the file extension

Comment: It depends on what you want to do... If you are receiving big files and it's a system with many users, it seems like a bad idea for system performance. But, technically, yes, you can open any uploaded file, but you should be more specific on what you want to validate, or at least, what file types you are expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the [MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) of the file, you can try comparing it to the value returned by `Files.probeContentType(tempFile)` (documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29)).

MIME types can have any number of optional parameters (for example "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"), so you may want to compare using the [MimeType.match](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimeType.html#match%28java.lang.String%29) method rather than just comparing the strings.

Answer (score 1):

If these are text-based files, consider using Apache Tika's [DefaultDetector](http://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/detect/DefaultDetector.html) class.

This will take an `InputStream` and Tika `Metadata` class and set the Content-Type metadata field, which is a standard mime-type (e.g. - text/html, application/xml, etc). Check the output from that against your expected mime-type to verify the file is "valid".

Beware though, this will consume your input stream, so be sure to make a copy if you want to use the file later.